# Register variables cause execution time to vary, why?

Tags: c

While fooling around i found out that the following code has a constant execution time(I used the Unix *time* command) as:
CODE:

```c
    #define bufferSize 5010
    void seperateDataTo50DigitNumbers(char *buffer){
        unsigned int length = strlen(buffer);
        for (int i = 1; i <= length; ++i){
            printf("%c", buffer[i - 1]);
            if(i%50 == 0){
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        char buffer[bufferSize];
        FILE *file;
        file = openFile();
        getAllData(file,buffer);
        seperateDataTo50DigitNumbers(buffer);
        closeFile(file);
        return 0;
    }
```

TIME:

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.000s
```

But I changed one small thing:

```c
    void seperateDataTo50DigitNumbers(char *buffer){
        register unsigned int length = strlen(buffer);
        for (register int i = 1; i <= length; ++i){
            printf("%c", buffer[i - 1]);
            if(i%50 == 0){
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

I expected the code to be faster as the variables are now stored in the register of the processor but instead, the time varies:

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.000s


real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s


real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Could anyone tell me the reason for this? And when should we use the register variables to optimise the code?

Comment: I would say you need a much longer time span - several seconds - to make a realistic comparison.

Comment: The execution time for this program is so little that you can't measure it with `time` and expect meaningful data. You need something that runs for several seconds - I would not trust anything below 10 sec

Comment: and it is far the time the compiler needed our help like with register to produce a good code ... Did you produce the assembler ( option -S) in the two cases to compare ?

Comment: compile with -Ofast and the difference will vanish. I bet you compile with the optimizations turned off. `register` has no real use in the modern compilers (no one is actually compiling without the optimizations)

Comment: OT: Even if it is perfectly valid to write `for (int i = 1; i <= length; ++i){` it is not common to start loops with 1. In C we always start at zero

Comment: BTW your function spends 99% of the time in the printf and the rest of it has a less than marginal influence on the execution time

Comment: There will be a difference if the console has to scroll its output, or if the executable is already in memory cache for a repeat run.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if **r.c** is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void seperateDataTo50DigitNumbersR(char *buffer){
    REGISTER unsigned int length = strlen(buffer);
    for (REGISTER int i = 1; i <= length; ++i){
        printf("%c", buffer[i - 1]);
        if(i%50 == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I do :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -S -O3 -DREGISTER= r.c -o r.s1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -S -O3 -DREGISTER=register r.c -o r.s2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ diff r.s1 r.s2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

the generate code are exactely the same, and I am not surprised

- first the compilers are very good and do not need uour help to produce a good code
- second you call a function (*printf*) so it is not possible to have the values all the time in registers except on CPU saving page of registers ... and in that case the compiler does that by itself

Out of that the execution times are too small (and not done in part associated to the registers but surely the *printf* executing more code) and the differences are not significant